# cakephp pass foreign key to add method in controller

Tags: cakephp

i have two tables persons and numbers. persons has a hasMany association with numbers, while numbers has a belongsTo association with persons. i also have a view method in the persons controller which displays the information about that person (including all the numbers associated to him). i also want to add an link to add a new number to that person. i was successful in passing the primary key of the person to the add method, but cant include it to the form in the add's view. i tried placing it in $this->data and adding a hidden field to the view, and using set() and assigning it as a default value to a hidden field in the view, but to no avail. any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer passing the person ID in the GET request itself.

In your numbers controller.

```
function add($personId = null) {
   //code
   $this->set('personId', $personId);
}
```

In your view, modify your form helper to post to a different URL with the person ID on the end

```
echo $this->Form->create('Number', array('url' => '/admin/number/add' . $personId));
```

Now when the form posts the data, the `$personId` is passed to the method so you don't need to access it via the data variable.